# ADF: jquery to point to specific element on page

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I am using jdev11.1.1.6

If i need to scroll to top of page..this works perfectly..

```
var scrollTop = function (event) {
$('.mainWrapper,body,html').animate( {
scrollTop : 0
}, 'slow');
}
```

I call it from pqr.jsff as

```
<af:commandLink text="click test" clientComponent="true" id="col7">
<af:clientListener method="scrollTop " type="click"/>
</af:commandLink>
```

[link where it directs it to specific element](http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2010/01/smoothly-scroll-to-an-element-without-a-jquery-plugin/)

I modified my function as below but it doesn't work for me

```
var scrollToSpecificPosition= function (event) {
$('.mainWrapper,body,html').animate( {
scrollTop : $("#gl1").offset().top
}, 'slow');
}
```

gl1 is the id where i wish to point

```
<af:goLink id="gl1" text="test"></af:goLink>
```

I call it from pqr.jsff as

```
<af:commandLink text="click test" clientComponent="true" id="col7">
<af:clientListener method="scrollToSpecificPosition" type="click"/>
</af:commandLink>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, problem is an Id field. 
"gl1" id is right identificator for adf component, but in html-dom it will be a bit different, since adf component itself may have complex html structure and to keep id's unique adf will add a parents id's to it as a prefix, etc.
One more thing. You have to check that **clientComponent** option is set to "**true**", to make sure that this component will be available in dom. Then find with something like FireBug real component id,

it may look a bit more complex, something like "pt1:pg1:gl1:link". And if you sure that your code will always run in the same enviroment, you can hardcode this id.
Another options, is to use mask to find your component.

Also you can try to use AdfPage (native js lib) to get access to the adf components by their original id (though its not that easy to use and it have some limitation too).